# Heroku Unexpected token '<' Deployment error, leading to blank page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, heroku-cli

I have been facing an unknown error after deploying on Heroku namely:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

However, deployment on GitHub pages works fine so I am unsure of the issue. Everything is working fine, except the actual page is just blank. When I view sources, it looks like this: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TN5l.png)

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.8.2",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.5.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.5.2",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.5.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "autosuggest-highlight": "^3.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.1.1",
    "react-countup": "^6.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.29.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.8",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.4",
    "react-text-typist": "^1.0.9",
    "react-typist": "^2.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --max_old_space_size=2560 node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start",
    "build": "node --max_old_space_size=2560 node_modules/.bin/react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3",
    "sass": "^1.48.0"
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: To deploy a react app on github pages, you have to add `"homepage: './'` to your `package.json` before building, because now you are absolute paths. And you would know that if you would open network tab in the devtools.
You didn't show any code so how could we know what else is going wrong?

Comment: Actually its my Heroku that is not working, but my GitHub pages seems fine. I have added my package.json file, hopefully it provides more information.

Comment: So what differs in the process of deploying on heroku and on GH? Can you explain how you do it?